# What is the most practical way to list all the installed packages in Sublime Text 3?

Tags: sublimetext, sublimetext3, sublime-text-plugin

I installed a bunch of packages lately on my Sublime Text 3 Editor. 
I don't keep track of what I installed, but now I would like to know all the packages that I've installed, just to keep as a reference.

I tried type : cmd + shift + P , then type : list

[image]

After see **Pckage Control: List Packages** then press **Enter**

I will then see all the list of packages. Great, but not yet perfect !

[image]

I'm wondering if there is a better way to list them in a much more readable format, can-copy them if possible.

What is the most practical way to list all the installed packages in Sublime Text 3 ?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Assuming you're using Package Control to install everything, you can get the full list of installed packages by going to **`Preferences -> Package Settings -> Package Control -> Settings-User`**. This will open up the user settings for Package Control in JSON format (just like all other Sublime settings files), and within it the `"installed_packages"` list contains every single package installed via Package Control, regardless of whether it includes a submenu in **`Preferences -> Package Settings`** or not.

---

It will look something like this.

```
{
    "bootstrapped": true,
    "in_process_packages":
    [
    ],
    "installed_packages":
    [
        "Package Control",
        "PyCover",
        "Python 3",
        "SublimeLinter",
        "SublimeLinter-csslint",
        "SublimeLinter-html-tidy",
        "SublimeLinter-jshint",
        "SublimeLinter-json",
        "SublimeLinter-lua",
        "SublimeLinter-pyflakes",
        "SublimeLinter-pyyaml",
        "SublimeREPL"
    ]
}
```

Comment: Based on this answer, I wrote a little shell script (sublpm, aka: Sublime Package Manager) in my dotfiles that reads from this file and lists the packages. In case it's helpful for anyone: https://github.com/0xdevalias/dotfiles/blob/devalias/bin/sublpm#L65-L71

Answer (score 1):

I just notice if we go to top menu and click on :

## Sublime Text > Preferences > Package Settings

We will see a list of all the packages that we installed.

[image]

Comment: Please note that this only covers packages with settings... there might be packages which do not appear in this menu.

Answer (score 0):

Try `Preferences` >  `Browser packages` and it should open the folder on your hard disk where all the packages are installed.

Comment: This is only true for ST2, and in that case it includes the built-in packages as well as the third-party ones. In ST3 (which the OP is using), most packages (unless they contain a `.no-sublime-package` file) are zipped into `.sublime-package` files and stored in `Installed Packages`. See my answer for a way to get a list of all installed packages in text format.